# не знаю как правильно прописать function* getAllPostsWorker

Tags: reactjs, api, jsx, worker

застряла на таком моменте не знаю как правильно прописать в saga функцию worker, чтобы получить посты

```
const API = create({
  baseURL: "https://api.spaceflightnewsapi.net",
});

const getPosts = (offset: number, search?: string, ordering?: string) => {
  return API.get("/v3/blogs/", { limit: PER_PAGE, search, offset,ordering });
};
```

это то, что я для примера написала

```
function* getAllPostsWorker(action: PayloadAction<GetAllPostsPayload>) {
  yield put(setAllPostsLoading(true));
  const { offset,search, ordering } = action.payload;
  const { ok, data, problem }: ApiResponse<AllPostsResponse> = yield call(
    API.getPosts,
    offset,
    search,
    ordering
  );
  if (ok && data) {
    yield put(setAllPosts({ cardList: data.results, postsCount: data.count }));
  } else {
    console.warn("Error getting all posts", problem);
  }
  yield put(setAllPostsLoading(false));
}
```